# Display Scrollbar when keyboard appears

Tags: android

Good Day,

I'm having this problem, where is the scroll bar is not showing when the keyboard pops up. I would like to see the scroll bar every time or at least when the keyboard pops up not just when the device has smaller screens. Below is my xml.

Note: I already added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and still not showing up. Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:background="@drawable/othersother">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:text="ACTIVATE DEALER"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView13" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activeretname"
    android:hint="Full Name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activeretnumber"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activeretnumber"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activeretnumber"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activeretusername"
    android:hint="Desired Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activeretname"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activeretname"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activeretname" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activeretsponsor"
    android:hint="Sponsor Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activeretusername"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activeretusername"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activeretusername" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activeretplacement"
    android:hint="Placement Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activeretsponsor"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activeretsponsor"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activeretsponsor" />

<TextView
    android:text="Select Group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activeretplacement"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView16" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="A"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/activereta"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
    android:checked="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="B"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/activeretb"
    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/activereta"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/activereta"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView13" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activeretcity"
    android:hint="City or Municipality"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activereta"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activeretplacement"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activeretplacement" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activeretnumber"
    android:hint="Mobile Number"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/activeretcode"
    android:hint="Activation Code"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activeretnumber"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activeretnumber" />

<Button
    android:text="SEND"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:id="@+id/activeretsend"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activeretcity"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect when the keyboard is shown (there are some hacks people have come up with, but they aren't accurate-  they have false positives or negatives).  So you can't have a scrollbar appear only when the keyboard is up.  Your best bet is to either keep the scrollbar on at all times (with android:fadeScrollbars="false" on the scrollview) if you really want this feature.  softInputMode resize may work better for you here, as I'm not sure if panning is sufficient to awaken scrollbars or not.

Comment: Scrollbar not showing up even with softInputMode and when fadeScrollbars is set to false.